# Effecient way to match value based on column AND row names

Tags: r

I am trying to extract a value from a `data.frame` by matching to another `data.frame`'s column names *and* row names. Then evaluate a logical condition on that value to potentially edit the reference data frame. Here's an example:

```
# Data frame of cars and cities. I would like to fill this data frame
# with the maximum observed speed for a given car manufacturer in that city
df <- data.frame(NYC = rep(0, 3),
                 ATL = rep(0, 3),
                 LA = rep(0, 3),
                 row.names = c("Ford", "Nissan", "Honda"))

# Observational data that I pull speeds from
obs <- data.frame(Make = c("Ford", "Ford", "Honda", "Ford", "Nissan", "Nissan"),
                  City = c("NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "ATL", "LA", "LA"),
                  Speed = c(70, 85, 70, 75, 90, 85))

# An example of what the final df might look like
final <- data.frame(NYC = c(85, 0, 70),
                    ATL = c(75, 0, 0),
                    LA = c(0, 90, 0),
                    row.names = c("Ford", "Nissan", "Honda"))
```

The challenge is not only in how to effectively reference the column/row names, but additionally I have **billions** of observations split over thousands of `obs` objects. Thus, I can only keep a certain number of `obs` in memory.

The approach that makes sense to me here is to:

1. Read in as many observations as I can
2. Find the maximum speeds and store them in `df`
3. Clear the old observations out for new ones and repeat step 2

Obviously creating and looping through a vector of the column/rows names is too slow. I tried to utilize an `apply` here but couldn't quite figure it out. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called data pivoting/reshaping:

```
pivot_wider(obs, names_from = City, values_from = Speed,
                values_fn = max, values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Make     NYC   ATL    LA
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Ford      85    75     0
2 Honda     70     0     0
3 Nissan     0     0    90
```

---

```
reshape2::dcast(obs, Make~City, max, fill = 0, value.var = 'Speed')
    Make ATL LA NYC
1   Ford  75  0  85
2  Honda   0  0  70
3 Nissan   0 90   0
```

---

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(obs), Make~City, max, fill = 0, value.var = 'Speed')
     Make ATL LA NYC
1:   Ford  75  0  85
2:  Honda   0  0  70
3: Nissan   0 90   0
```

Comment: This does work and is similar to @Dylan_Gomes answer. Do you have a solution for portion regarding the iterative updating of `df` with the highest observed speeds after pivoting/reshaping?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am missing part of your question, but it seems to me you don't actually need the initialized `df`:

```
obs <- data.frame(Make = c("Ford", "Ford", "Honda", "Ford", "Nissan", "Nissan"),
                  City = c("NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "ATL", "LA", "LA"),
                  Speed = c(70, 85, 70, 75, 90, 85))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

(final <- obs %>% group_by(Make,City) %>% summarise(Max.Speed = max(Speed)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Make,names_from = City,values_from = Max.Speed) )

# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Groups:   Make [3]
  Make     ATL   NYC    LA
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Ford      75    85    NA
2 Honda     NA    70    NA
3 Nissan    NA    NA    90
```

If you want to fill the NA with 0, as you have:

```
final[is.na(final)]<-0

final

# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Groups:   Make [3]
  Make     ATL   NYC    LA
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Ford      75    85     0
2 Honda      0    70     0
3 Nissan     0     0    90
```

Comment: You're right, as the question is stated I do not need the initial `df`. I forgot to add that my observations are split over thousands of `obs` objects. Please see my edits in the question. Ideally I would like to use `df` to store my results as I cycle through observations, but perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: @grapestory In that case you do not need to reshape. One option is to only find max for the current data. ie `aggregate(Speed~., obs, max)`, store this, clear the old observations and read the new ones, bind the old maximums to the data, find maximum of the new data binded with the old data. This will become the new maximum. Repeat. At the end you will have the maximum that you want,

Comment: @Onyambu That solution is simple and effective. I didn't even think of that. I believe your original answer will be the most helpful to anyone who comes across this post, and you were the first person to solve the complete problem, so I will accept that answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please the `left_join` to merge the df with updated obs as below

```r
library(tidyverse)

obs2 <- obs %>% group_by(Make,City) %>% arrange(Make,City,Speed) %>% slice_tail(n=1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Make, names_from = City, values_from = Speed, values_fill = 0)

# get the names of the df
vars <- names(df)

obs2 %>% left_join(df %>% rownames_to_column('Make'), by=c('Make',all_of(vars))) %>% 
  column_to_rownames('Make')
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
       ATL NYC LA
Ford    75  85  0
Honda    0  70  0
Nissan   0   0 85
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear in my question. I need to constantly by replacing the values in `df` with the highest speed (for a given Make and City). I follow how you create `obs2` (though it's missing the max speed part), however I tried your `left_join` with a new `obs` and it failed due to duplicate names.

Comment: instead of the max I am using the `slice_tail` where I select the max record after sorting with Make & City. I am not sure why we get the duplicate names, is it in the `df` we have duplicate names, even in the `obs2` we should not have duplicate names, please let me where and which names have duplicates

Comment: That's what I thought `slice_tail` was doing but I am not sure it's working. For example, in the data here the speed for Nissan in LA should be 90, not 85. As for the error, here is the exact issue `Error:
! Column name "Make" must not be duplicated.`

Comment: I updated the code to include `arrange`, hope it will resolve the issue

Comment: The `arrange` does solve the max issue, however the `left_join` still doesn't update `df` to contain the highest speeds of any `obs`. That `left_join` statement just populates `df` with the pivot-ed values from `obs`, but if I `left_join` with a new `obs` object with lower speeds then `df` would then contain those lower speeds.